# setting up typescript but not getting type errors

Tags: typescript

I'm new to typescript, been doing a course in code academy and now trying to do the tutorial with mosh so now starting to set up everything.
in the start of the tutorial he shows type issue that comes when you write this simple code:

```
let age: number = 20;
age = 'a';
```

and then he shows the obvious error - which I'm not getting for some reason.
I checked the version of 'tsc' to check I have it, my file is called 'index.ts' and I have the tsconfig.json file.
I've been trying to search for a solution online and to try to set it up again but nothing works :(
[image of my code that not showing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lg7lb.jpg)

Comment: Can you show us your `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: Perhaps you need to set in strict - as asked by @brc-dd please share your `tsconfig` file

Comment: my tsconfig.json file is too long so I only share the uncomment parts

`{
  "compilerOptions": {"target": "es2016",   "module": "commonjs",  "esModuleInterop": true,  "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true, "strict": true,     "skipLibCheck": true                                 /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
  }
}`

Comment: Have you specified [`include`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#include) in your tsconfig?

Comment: I just went to the link and added the 'include' to my tsconfig file, refreshed VScode but nothing changed :(